# Using a variable in more than 1 file

Tags: discord.js

**TL:DR - I need help using a variable in more than 1 file**

Currently I have a bot that counts how many times the word ":p" has been used. It adds that number to the variable "numberofp". On a separate file I want to call the variable on an embed but it says numberofp is undefined. Code is below. If you would like more code just ask!

```
code for index.js
   // variables
   var numberofp = 0;
client.on('message', (message) => {
if(message.author.id = 714544589305806868){
    if(message.content.includes(':p')){
        numberofp = numberofp + 1;
        console.log('Porsha_boy said :p, so far it has been sent this many times:', numberofp);
    }
}
```

})

```
Code for embed

const db = require("quick.db")
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'rub',
    description: 'a command that tells you what your ping is',
    execute(message, args, Discord){
            // Basic embed
            var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor(numberofp)
              .setColor("#34BDE1")
              console.log('working')
              


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the variable to be visible from the module outside:

wordcounter.js

```
let counter = 0;

function increase(a = 1) {
  counter += a;
}

function getCounter() {
  return counter;
}

exports.increase = increase;
exports.getCounter = getCounter;
```

clientone.js

```
const wc = require('./wordcounter');

wc.increase();
wc.increase(2);
wc.increase(5);
```

clienttwo.js

```
const wc = require('./wordcounter');

wc.increase(1);
wc.increase(1);
wc.increase(5);
```

index.js

```
const wc = require('./wordcounter');
const c1 = require('./clientone');
const c2 = require('./clienttwo');

console.log(wc.getCounter());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, could you tell me what the point of clientone and clienttwo is?

Comment: @Quistty just to prove you can change the value of the variable from multiple files.